# Why does WinHttpQueryDataAvailable say 0 bytes are available?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, http

Synchronous operation. `GetLastError` = 0, `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` itself returns TRUE (i.e. OK) yet the number of bytes to read = 0

Any idea what this means? It normally works fine (reading JPEG stream from a camera), but occasionally gets stuck here (which prompts the code to reconnect).

According to MSDN, `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` shouldn't have returned: "If the session is synchronous, the request waits until data becomes available."

Code extract here:

```
g_HSession = WinHttpOpen( L"Jet", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );

ResultsOk = WinHttpSendRequest( 
    hRequest,
    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
    0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
    0, 0);

// End the request.
if (ResultsOk)
{
    ResultsOk = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

    DWORD BytesToRead = 0;

    if (WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &BytesToRead ))
    {
        if (BytesToRead) // THIS IS SOMETIMES 0 - seems wrong to me
        {
            if (WinHttpReadData( hRequest, pReadPos, min(BytesToRead, (unsigned)SizeRemaining), &NumRead ))
            {
                ...etc!
```

Comment: This may apply, see Remarks, third paragraph. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underlying HTTP response has been successfully received, but it was empty (that is, zero length response) or all the data has been read and closed. `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` indicates this by returning `TRUE` still showing zero count of data available.

Think of:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: What is the appropriate response to this value? Still call WinHttpReadData? Or something else. It's a little strange as I'm expecting a continuous stream of JPEGs

Comment: Use Wireshark to verify if there is actually an entity body in the http message; I've never had WinHttp fail to deliver a body to me (creepy).

Comment: Just open another request on the same connection. Continuous stream of JPEGs sounds like an endless stream from an IP camera, but cameras are often quite buggy nowadays so, if for some reason a camera gets you such a surprise, you open a new request and attempt to resume the transmission. Also be sure to use network sniffer to check actual traffic (as suggested above).

Comment: Well, that's good know you think it's creepy. I was worried I was supposed to handle it differently! As it stands (stood) when it happens I close the connection and try again. Unfortunately the new connection tends to do the same thing instantly (for a few cycles at least).

Comment: There are 1000+ models of IP cameras out there, which deliver JPEG and/or M-JPEG. Hundreds have ridiculous issues with HTTP compliance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `BytesToRead` variable is an unsigned long as it is supposed to be?

You can try restructuring your code to look more like the example right under the "Examples" header on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Does [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/45ccd91c-6794-4f9b-8f4f-865c76cc146d) help at all?

Unrelated to question, but if you're using Visual Studio you can go into your project settings (something like Project Properties > Project Defaults > Character Set) and then you don't have to put the L before your strings as you do in `g_HSession = WinHttpOpen( L"Jet"...`.