# WinHttp blank return (Possibly with grabbing data too fast)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

While using the WinHttp request, the call is made successfully however depending if the call takes time to populate in the site, then the value will return nothing and report no errors. We are using a cfc file as the returned response for the api. Some calls will work while others will not (usually the ones that take 2+ seconds to return the call and populate the data).

Sadly the api is private and I cannot provide the call (proprietary information). But I am open to all suggestions and will provide the code that calls the data (which does not contain any proprietary data).

```
string response;

DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
    hConnect = NULL,
    hRequest = NULL;

// Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

// Specify an HTTP server.
if (hSession) {
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, s2ws(host).c_str(),
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);
    if (!WinHttpSetTimeouts(hSession, 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000))
        printf("Error %u in WinHttpSetTimeouts.\n", GetLastError());
}

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", s2ws(call).c_str(),
        NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
        WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
        WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH | WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

// Send a request.
if (hRequest) {
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
        WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
        WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
        0, 0);
}

// End the request.
if (bResults) {
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, 0);
}

// Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
if (bResults) {
    do {
        // Check for available data.
        dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)) {
            printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                GetLastError());

            break;
        }

        if (!dwSize)
            break;

        // Allocate space for the buffer.
        pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
        if (!pszOutBuffer) {
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            break;
        }
        // Read the data.
        ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

        if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
            dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
            printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
        else {
            response = response + string(pszOutBuffer);
        }

        // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
        delete[] pszOutBuffer;

        // This condition should never be reached since WinHttpQueryDataAvailable
        // reported that there are bits to read.
        if (!dwDownloaded)
            break;
    } while (dwSize > 0);
}

if (response == "") {
    wcout << "Value is blank: " << bResults << endl << GetLastError() << endl << response.c_str() << endl;
}

// Report any errors.
if (!bResults)
    printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

// Close any open handles.
if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

return response;
```

Edit: also using the curl lib also produces the same result of returning no data (it will return data on other api's)

Edit 2: I have also tried the solution from this example [WinHttpSendRequest fails with ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554388/winhttpsendrequest-fails-with-error-winhttp-secure-failure)
It also fails to grab the data, so I am unsure why it fails to grab it.

Edit 3: Fiddler Reports
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Length: 0 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 
Set-Cookie: CFID=randomCookie;Path=/ 
Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=0;Path=/ 
Return-Format: plain 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:15:01 GMT

Comment: What does Fiddler and/or Wireshark say?

Comment: When I use Fiddler it returns nothing. It doesn't show the response or the call. When I make the call myself in the browser it will show up then, other than that how do I get it to show up from the winhttp call?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-fiddler-with-winhttp

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: CFID=randomCookie;Path=/
Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=0;Path=/
Return-Format: plain
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:15:01 GMT

Raw return of request

Comment: `Content-Length: 0` anyway you can/must yourself call `WinHttpQueryHeaders` with `WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF` for print all (optional), and  `WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE` + (in case 200) `WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH`

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you mean by that. Do you mean I have to check that the content length is greater than 0 before receiving the response?

Comment: @MannyKSoSo - this is depend from your programlogic, but in most case yes, need check content length and before this http status

Comment: The problem I am having is how to apply what you have said. Where should I be putting in a check for `WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH > 0`. Should it be before the request end? From what I have tried I still can't get it to grab the data. Even when I query the length.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Return-Format: plain
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 13:14:43 GMT
--Raw return of when I make the call via the browser

Comment: What's the value of the `dwSize` return by `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable`. `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` still displays zero available data by returning TRUE to indicate that it has successfully received the underlying HTTP response, but it is empty (that is, zero length response) or has read and closed all data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214909/why-does-winhttpquerydataavailable-say-0-bytes-are-available

Comment: You are correct that it is returning 0 for the `dwSize` and that `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` does return true as the value (since the return is read and its just blank), however I know there is data that should be returned by the api. Since this call takes some time (there is quite a bit of data) and the .cfc takes a second to populate the output, when it reads the data it reads blank. So I think all I need is to just wait an extra second if the value is blank, but I'm not sure where to put the check in.

Comment: @RbMm Querying the data after the request I get these values `WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH = 5` which is the ending characters (content length is still 0) and `WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE = 19` which shouldn't be 19? Not sure why it is 19 but it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same issue. By executing the following on the command prompt, the problem was solved.

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```